# JSR 363 : formating a volume unit in decilitre

Tags: java, units-of-measurement, jsr363

Formatting a volume unit works correctly in millilitres and centilitres but fails for decilitres.

```
import static tec.units.ri.unit.Units.LITRE;

import javax.measure.Unit;
import javax.measure.format.UnitFormat;
import javax.measure.quantity.Volume;
import javax.measure.spi.ServiceProvider;

import static tec.units.ri.unit.MetricPrefix.*;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final UnitFormat unitFormat =    ServiceProvider.current().getUnitFormatService().getUnitFormat();

        final Unit<Volume> MILLILITRE = MILLI(LITRE);
        final Unit<Volume> CENTILITRE = CENTI(LITRE);
        final Unit<Volume> DECILITRE = DECI(LITRE);

        final String mL = unitFormat.format(MILLILITRE);
        final String cL = unitFormat.format(CENTILITRE);
        final String dL = unitFormat.format(DECILITRE);

        System.out.println(mL);
        System.out.println(cL);
        System.out.println(dL);
    }
}
```

This code prints :

```
ml
cl
㎥/10000.0
```

How to format the volume unit "DECILITRE" to display "dl"?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. 
https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/unit-ri/issues/54
shows, that prefixes are not automatically propagated across all units in `SimpleUnitFormat`.

For out-of-the-box units coming with an implementation, SimpleUnitFormat should know them. Will check out, if it can be addressed, see https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/unit-ri/issues/60.

Most other `UnitFormat` implementations e.g. those found in the Java SE 8+ implementation [uom-se](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/uom-se) or extension modules deal with this in a different way. It is a known limitation of `SimpleUnitFormat` (which is why it's called "simple") to ensure it works the same way on very small systems running Java ME Embedded. If your application is able to use Java SE 8 and above or you have no problem updating the Java version, please consider this. At this point the RI must be backward compatible with ME Embedded, so the default `UnitFormat` is `SimpleUnitFormat` for all implementations. Calling

```
final UnitFormat unitFormat =     
     ServiceProvider.current().getUnitFormatService().getUnitFormat("EBNF");
```

on top of the Java SE implementation will get you the EBNFUnitFormat and based on unit tests and lack of issue reports it should work there.

Regards,
Werner

Comment: Seems code works by calling `getUnitFormat("ASCII")`. Would appear to be missing line for `DEFAULT.label(MetricPrefix.DECI(LITRE), "dl");` at line 963 of `SimpleUnitFormat` (version 1.0.2).

Comment: Looks like that slipped, we have it in uom-se. Thanks for pointing out. It should be in an upcoming Update pack. Aiming to do that over Easter, so approx. a week from now. 1.0.3-SNAPSHOT will work immediately, please try it there.