# Setting an alias name on a ProductUnit fails to return that alias during serialization

Tags: java, units-of-measurement, jsr363, jsr-275

### Task

I am trying to set an alias name on a UOM `ProductUnit`to allow the unit to be displayed in a human-friendly name in JSON/my frontend. The unit in question is "kg/h", so a mass-flow rate derived from the SI basic units "kg" and "s".

However, while setting the alias via the `SimpleUnitFormat` method

```
public abstract void alias(Unit<?> unit, String alias);
```

returns no error, the alias name is disregarded. I am not sure where I go wrong, as code comments on `SimpleUnitFormat` say "Attaches a system-wide alias to this unit".

### Problem

I expect to be able to parse the string "kg/h" into a Indrya unit and if serializing that unit, get back "kg/h". What I instead get back is "(kg/s)*3600"

The code in form of a unit-test:

```
public class UnitsTest {
    private static final SimpleUnitFormat fs;
    private static final Unit<MassFlowRate> KILOGRAM_PER_HOUR;
    static {
        fs = SimpleUnitFormat.getInstance();
        // KILOGRAM_PER_SECOND is defined in si.uom.SI
        KILOGRAM_PER_HOUR = KILOGRAM_PER_SECOND.multiply(3600);
        fs.alias(KILOGRAM_PER_SECOND.multiply(3600), "kg/h");
    }


    @Test
    void testFlowRate() {
        String unitName = "kg/h";
        Unit<? extends Quantity<?>> rate = fs.parse(unitName);
        Assertions.assertEquals(unitName, rate.toString()); //<-- fails
        Assertions.assertEquals(rate, KILOGRAM_PER_HOUR);
    }
}
```

And the `assertEquals()` fails with the following:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :kg/h
Actual   :(kg/s)*3600
```

As you can see, the String-representation of the derived unit ("(kg/s)*3600") is physically correct, but not what my end-users would want to see.

### What I tried

Replacing `rate.toString()` with `rate.getName()` doesn't work either, it just yields `null`. Replacing `rate.toString()` with `rate.getSymbol()` doesn't work either, it also yields `null`.

Another attempt with using the `alternate()` method instead of an alias like this:

```
KILOGRAM_PER_SECOND.multiply(3600).alternate("kg/h");
```

fails with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The parent unit: (kg/s)*3600 is not an unscaled SI unit
    at tech.units.indriya.unit.AlternateUnit.<init>(AlternateUnit.java:91)
    at tech.units.indriya.AbstractUnit.alternate(AbstractUnit.java:336)
```

Based [on this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43308841/2535335), I tried switching to `EBNFUnitFormat` but that doesn't allow aliases.

I am sure I am misunderstanding the whole UoM/Indrya library here, but IDK how.

### Environment

The problem comes up both on Windows and Linux. I am using Java 13 and here's the relevant parts of my POM:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tech.units</groupId>
        <artifactId>indriya</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>si.uom</groupId>
        <artifactId>si-units</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was easy:

```
fs.label(KILOGRAM_PER_HOUR, "kg/h");
```

This way, the unit gets serialized to `kg/h` in `toString()`